# Structure of Modules and Elementary Divisors Matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

Find the structure of the module $\mathbb{Z}^{3}/N$ where $N$ is spanned by $(1,1,1),(6,3,2), (4,1,0)$.

---

I checked that the above vectors are not linearly independent.

I have generally learned that for a basis of $N$ (not a generating set), we can apply the elementary divisors theorem to a basis $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ of $N$ and a basis $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$ of $R^{n}$ (in the general case where we have a surjective homomorphism of $R$-modules $f:R^{n} \rightarrow M$ and $\mathrm{Ker}(f)=N$) to find the respective change of bases $x_{j}'$ and $y_{j}'$ respectively.

If the exercise given were for a linearly independent set, one would form the matrix $A$ out from the linearly independent set and then perform row operations until the matrix of elementary divisors is found.

What would be a way to extend this idea to a generating set of $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ instead of a basis of it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the Smith normal form of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&6&4\\1&3&1\\1&2&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

There is an algorithm to do this, however the fastest way is using Fitting ideals. The Fitting ideals $I_i$ are the ideals generated by the $i \times i$-minors of the matrix, by computing them we find

$I_1 = (1), I_2= (1), I_3=(0).$

The Smith normal form is the unique diagonal matrix with the same Fitting ideals, which is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

and we find $\mathbb Z^3/N \cong \mathbb Z$.

It would be interesting to find the generator. It is the equivalence class of $\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, since we have

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}1&4&3\\1&1&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}=1.$$

So these $3$ vectors form a basis of $\mathbb Z^3$, i.e.

$$\mathbb Z^3 = \langle \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \rangle \oplus  \langle \begin{pmatrix}4\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} \rangle \oplus \langle \begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} \rangle = N \oplus \langle \begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} \rangle.$$

Comment: Great, thanks. This argument would work since we can reduce the set of generators of $N$ into a basis of $N$ (thus spanning the same set)? Why would this be the case? 

I guess then this would allow us to find the Smith normal form in the standard way. As well, what do you mean with the equivalence class of the vector $(3,1,0)$? I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: Notice that for the first part of my answer, I never used that we can reduce the set of generators for $N$ into a basis...I just computed the Smith normal form, which ALWAYS works like this.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I did some computations regarding the Smith normal form and in the end the fact that these are just generators doesn't affect the result in any way (the dimension of the matrices end up agreeing).